# how to submit multiple form data using jQuery ??

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I have 8 forms all separate, and styled in css as a slider, and each form is accessed by clicking the back or next button. So how do i submit all form data at once when i click the last next button or the next button on the last slider.
Right now, if i submit my data using the jQuery .submit() function only the last form data is submitted. I want all my form data to be submitted at once. Any fixes or solutions are much appreciated. Thanks!

```
<% include partials/header %>

<div class="container overalls">
    <div class = "box-survey">
       <div class = "question">
        <p>1 | What software stack do you prefer to code in ?</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "answers">
        <form action="/survey" method="POST" class = "answer-list">
            <ul>
                <li class = "options1">
                    <input type="radio" value = "1" name = "options1" id = "r1">
                    <label for="r1">MEAN Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options1">
                    <input type="radio" value = "2" name = "options1" id = "r2">
                    <label for="r2">LAMP Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options1">
                    <input type="radio" value = "3" name = "options1" id = "r3">
                    <label for="r3">MERN Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options1">
                    <input type="radio" value = "4" name = "options1" id = "r4">
                    <label for="r4">Other Stacks</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "box-survey">
    <div class = "question">
        <p>2 | What software stack do you prefer to code in ?</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "answers">
        <form action="/survey" method="POST" class = "answer-list">
            <ul>
                <li class = "options2">
                    <input type="radio" value = "5" name = "options2" id = "r5">
                    <label for="r5">MEAN Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options2">
                    <input type="radio" value = "6" name = "options2" id = "r6">
                    <label for="r6">LAMP Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options2">
                    <input type="radio" value = "7" name = "options2" id = "r7">
                    <label for="r7">MERN Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options2">
                    <input type="radio" value = "8" name = "options2" id = "r8">
                    <label for="r8">Other Stacks</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "box-survey">
    <div class = "question">
        <p>3 | What software stack do you prefer to code in ?</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "answers">
        <form action="/survey" method="POST" class = "answer-list">
            <ul>
                <li class = "options3">
                    <input type="radio" value = "9" name = "options3" id = "r9">
                    <label for="r9">MEAN Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options3">
                    <input type="radio" value = "10" name = "options3" id = "r10">
                    <label for="r10">LAMP Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options3">
                    <input type="radio" value = "11" name = "options3" id = "r11">
                    <label for="r11">MERN Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options3">
                    <input type="radio" value = "12" name = "options3" id = "r12">
                    <label for="r12">Other Stacks</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "box-survey">
    <div class = "question">
        <p>4 | What software stack do you prefer to code in ?</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "answers">
        <form action="/survey" method="POST" class = "answer-list">
            <ul>
                <li class = "options4">
                    <input type="radio" value = "13" name = "options4" id = "r13">
                    <label for="r13">MEAN Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options4">
                    <input type="radio" value = "14" name = "options4" id = "r14">
                    <label for="r14">LAMP Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options4">
                    <input type="radio" value = "15" name = "options4" id = "r15">
                    <label for="r15">MERN Stack</label>
                </li>
                <hr>
                <li class = "options4">
                    <input type="radio" value = "16" name = "options4" id = "r16">
                    <label for="r16">Other Stacks</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "scroll-list">
    <div class="backB .col-md-2" onclick="plusDiv(-1)">
        <div class = "changer-circle-diff"></div>
        <button class="button-back">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "changer-circle .col-md-1" id = "circle1" onclick = "currentDiv(1)"></div>
    <div class = "changer-circle .col-md-1" id = "circle2" onclick = "currentDiv(2)"></div>
    <div class = "changer-circle .col-md-1" id = "circle3" onclick = "currentDiv(3)"></div>
    <div class = "changer-circle .col-md-1" id = "circle4" onclick = "currentDiv(4)"></div>
    <div class="nextB .col-md-2" onclick="plusDiv(1)"> 
        <button class="button-next">Next</button>  
        <div class = "changer-circle-diff"></div> 
    </div>                                                     
</div>
```

```
<% include partials/footer %>
```

Comment: So I'll ask the obvious question.  Why don't you put them all in a single form?

Comment: Use the single form is the best approch. Otherwsie you can try storing it in local storage and clear it after the submit. But not a good way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157532/can-i-submit-two-forms-with-one-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, to handle it with only one form is the best solution.
That being said, if you still want to post them separately, you can still go with :

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  $('form').each(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response); /* Or do anything else you need to do */
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Add the code inside the ready() to whatever function handles your next/previous actions with a check on whether it's the last next or not. Can't provide further code without said function's code

---

***To answer your comment on how to use a single form :***

I think this is a whole new question, since the way it will be processed will depend on your backend logic, but basically, on the view side (your html there), put all your code related to the form (inputs, labels.. ) into a single `form` tag (instead of having multiple `form` tags like you have actually)

You can keep your step-by-step logic by replacing the `form` tags you removed by `div` tags, keeping same classes names, and then adapt your javascript code so it uses `div`s instead of `form`s to handle the steps transition.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I am new to Web Design, Can you please tell me how i could make a single form with all my questions and answers ??